# Sharing Rule on LookUp Field

Tags: sharing

we have 5 customer profiles, and which ever user is assigned one of those profiles can only see 1 customer (account) record, and all customer child (contacts ) associated with that account. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define record sharing based on profile directly. One technique I've used in the past is to link a profile to a Public Group via a User trigger. When the user's profile changes, they're removed from the previous profile's Public Group, then added to the new Public Group. At that point, it's simply a matter of assigning the share to the Public Group, which could be as simple as manually sharing the account, though Sharing Rules could also be used if you really wanted to.

Comment: okay. What are the condition I have to check ?.which record ive to share account or contact records?.If I share account records automatically sharing will work in case of contact is also private?

Comment: @AnnappaPH set Accounts to Private, set Contacts to Controlled By Parent, then share the account.

Comment: User can see 1 account record?

Comment: @AnnappaPH If your security is set up correctly, then yes, they'd presumably see just one account record.